# WCF Service Client: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I've got a WCF Service running on my local IIS server. I've added it as a service reference to a C# Website Project and it adds fine and generates the proxy classes automatically.

However, when I try and call any of the service contracts, I get the following error:

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the
execution of the current web  request.
Please review the stack trace for more
information about the error and where
it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:
The content type text/html;
charset=utf-8 of the response message
does not match the content type of the
binding (application/soap+xml;
charset=utf-8). If using a custom
encoder, be sure that the
IsContentTypeSupported method is
implemented properly. The first 1024
bytes of the response were: '

function
bredir(d,u,r,v,c){var w,h,wd,hd,bi;var
b=false;var p=false;var
s=[[300,250,false],[250,250,false],[240,400,false],[336,280,false],[180,150,false],[468,60,false],[234,60,false],[88,31,false],[120,90,false],[120,60,false],[120,240,false],[125,125,false],[728,90,false],[160,600,false],[120,600,false],[300,600,false],[300,125,false],[530,300,false],[190,200,false],[470,250,false],[720,300,true],[500,350,true],[550,480,true]];if(typeof(window.innerHeight)=='number'){h=window.innerHeight;w=window.innerWidth;}else
if(typeof(document.body.offsetHeight)=='number'){h=document.body.offsetHeight;w=document.body.offsetWidth;}for(var
i=0;i

I also have a console application which also communicates with the WCF Service and the console app is able to call methods fine without getting this error.

Below are excerpts from my config files.

WCF Service Web.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="ScraperService" behaviorConfiguration="ScraperServiceBehavior">
         <endpoint address=""
                   binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                   bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IScraperService"
                   contract="IScraperService" />
         <endpoint address="mex" 
                   binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                   contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://example.com" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IScraperService"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
               <readerQuotas 
                     maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" 
                     maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
               <reliableSession 
                     enabled="false" ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
               <security mode="Message">
                   <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                            negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default"
                            establishSecurityContext="true" />
               </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="ScraperServiceBehavior">
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Website Project Service Client `Web.Config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IScraperService" 
              closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
              receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" 
              messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
              <readerQuotas 
                  maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                  maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                  maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession enabled="false"
                  ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
              <security mode="Message">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                       proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                       negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                       algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
          </binding>
       </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
<client>
        <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_IScraperService"
            address="http://example.com/ScraperService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IScraperService"
            contract="ScraperService.IScraperService" >
           <identity>
               <servicePrincipalName value="host/FreshNET-II" />
           </identity>
        </endpoint>
     </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How are you hosting this service?? In IIS ?? If so, then IIS dictates the service address - you cannot define your own base addresses (they're not used). So if you're in IIS, the address would be `http://yourserver/virtualdirectory/ScrapperService.svc` . Can you do a "View in Browser" on the *.svc file inside Visual Studio's Solution Explorer??

Comment: I tried to view the service from the IIS server and it returned a DNS error. Turned out that the service was only visible internally so when my client tried to access the service, it couldn't. All sorted, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try browsing to http://localhost/ScraperService.svc in the web browser on the server hosting the service, using the same Windows credentials that the client normally runs under.

I imagine that IIS is displaying an html error message of some description instead of returning xml as expected.

This also can occur when you have an http proxy server that performs internet filtering. My experience with ContentKeeper is that it intercepts any http/https traffic and blocks it as "Unmanaged Content" - all we get back is an html error message. To avoid this, you can add proxy server exception rules to Internet Explorer so that the proxy doesn't intercept traffic to your site:

Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings > Advanced > Proxy Settings

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. I logged onto the server and tried to view the service and I received a DNS error. Turns out that sites were only visible internally so when my WCF client tried to access the service, it couldn't and returned an error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not use proxy, but this answer inspired me to turn off in 'Automatically detect settings' in near previous proxy dialog, which helped

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 43):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by changing

```
<basicHttpBinding>
```

to

```
<basicHttpsBinding>
```

and also changed my URL to use https:// instead of http://.

Also in <endpoint> node, change

```
binding="basicHttpBinding"
```

to

```
binding="basicHttpsBinding"
```

This worked.

Comment: This was it for me.  The provider switched from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: That was my problem , The https instead of http.

Comment: This answer saved me so much trouble. I had to use the SoapClient constructor that accepted a binding object and use an instance of BasicHttpsBinding. Would have never figured it out.

Comment: Same for me as well - thanks - also had to change from HttpTransportBindingElement to HttpsTransportBindingElement
I am thinking the issue arises when you hit a service behind a HTTP only load balancer?

Comment: I've got the same error when I've hosted a WCF service in Azure App Service. In my case, issue was due to accessing http end point of app service having the setting HTTPS Only set to On. So, I've also followed above solution provided by @radkan to update WCF configurations to use https. Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

An HTML response from the web server normally indicates that an error page has been served instead of the response from the WCF service. My first suggestion would be to check that the user you're running the WCF client under has access to the resource.

Comment: How could I go about testing this? Both the WCF Client and the WCF Service are running on the same IIS server just under different domains during testing...

Comment: Is the WCF client an ASP.NET application running under IIS? If so, this will probably be running as the Network Service account, which has minimum privileges. You will need to either allow this account access to the directory in IIS or configure the WCF client to run as a different windows account.

Comment: What if the WCF client is a client test tool like soapUI or WCFStorm?

Answer (score 6):

what's going on is that you're trying to access the service using wsHttpBind, which use secured encrypted messages by default (secured Messages).
On other hand the netTcpBind uses Secured encrypted channels. (Secured Transport)... BUT basicHttpBind, doesn't require any security at all, and can access anonymous

SO. at the Server side, Add\Change this into your configuration.

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
     <binding name="wsbind"> 
         <security mode="Message">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
             <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
         </security>
     </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

then add change your endpoint to

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsbind" name="wshttpbind" contract="WCFService.IService" >
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: If your target server endpoint is using secure socket layer (SSL) certificate**

Change your .config setting from `basicHttpBinding` to `basicHttpsBinding`

I am sure, It will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As with many, in my situation I was also getting this because of an error. And sadly I could just read the CSS of the html error page.

The source of my problem was also a rewrite rule on the server. It was rewriting http to https.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the suggestions above, but what worked in the end was changing the Application Pool  managed pipeline from Integrated mode to Classic mode.
It runs in its own application pool - but it was the first .NET 4.0 service - all other servicves are on .NET 2.0 using Integrated pipeline mode.
Its just a standard WCF service using is https - but on Server 2008 (not R2) - using IIS 7 (not 7.5) .

Answer (score 2):

In my WCF serive project this issue is due to Reference of System.Web.Mvc.dll 's different version. So it may be compatibility issue of DLL's different version

When I use

**System.Web.Mvc.dll version 5.2.2.0** -> it thorows the **Error** The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message

but when I use
**System.Web.Mvc.dll version 4.0.0.0 or lower** -> it **works fine**.

I don't know the reason of different version DLL's issue but by changing the DLL's verison it works for me.

**This Error even generate when you add reference of other Project in your WCF Project and this reference project has different version of System.Web.Mvc DLL or could be any other DLL.**

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in my asp.net core 5 web api project to call a soap service. I resolved it by :

1.changing its url : return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://ourservice.com/webservices/service1.asmx?wsdl"); to **https**://ourservice.com/...

2. use these config in its Reference.cs :

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.TaxReturnSoap))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding();
            result.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            return result;
        }
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.TaxReturnSoap12))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            textBindingElement.WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            textBindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressingVersion.None);
            result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            httpBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
            httpBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            httpBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);
            return result;
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case a URL rewrite rule was messing with my service name, it was rewritten as lowercase and I was getting this error.

Make sure you don't lowercase WCF service calls.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to examine the configuration for your service and make sure that everything is ok. You can navigate to web service via the browser to see if the schema will be rendered on the browser.

You may also want to examine the credentials used to call the service.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't use network proxy, turning 'Automatically detect settings' in proxy dialog makes this exception go off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, but the client config was using a basicHttpBinding. The issue turned out to be that the service was using SOAP 1.2 and you can't specify SOAP 1.2 in a basicHttpBinding. I modified the client config to use a customBinding instead and everything worked. Here are the details of my customBinding for reference. The service I was trying to consume was over HTTPS using UserNameOverTransport.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="myBindingNameHere" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
        </security>
        <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
              messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </textMessageEncoding>
        <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="4194304"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Basic"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="4194304" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
              realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: where can I config username and password, it show "The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials."

Answer (score 1):

If your are using both wshttpbinding along with https request, then i resolved it by using the below configuration change.

```
 <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

X++
    `binding = endPoint.get_Binding();
    binding.set_UseDefaultWebProxy(false);`

Comment: Is this your answer if so please explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: sometime our program failed to find out the proxy sevrer because of some unknown reason in that case don't use the default proxy and set ip address of proxy in code. In that way it will start work

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
In my case this error appeared because the Application pool of the webservice had the wrong 32/64 bit setting. So this error needed the following fix: you go to the IIS, select the site of the webservice , go to Advanced setting and get the application pool. Then go to Application pools, select it, go to "Advanced settings..." , select the "Enable 32 bit applications" and make it Enable or Disable, according to the 32/64 bit type of your webservice.
If the setting is True, it means that it only allows 32 bit applications, so for 64 bit apps you have to make it "Disable" (default).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the web app connection string pointing to the wrong database server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening because my WCF web.config had a return character as its first line. It was even more frustrating because it was behind a load balancer and was happening only half the time (only one of the two web.configs had this problem).

Comment: That's pretty funny tbh

Answer (score 0):

This error happens also when :

`targetNamespace` is wrongly defined in the wsdl
or
when the ns2 is wrongly defined in the response (different from the ns in the request) . For example
request

```
<.. xmlns:des="http://zef/">
```

response

```
<ns2:authenticateResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xyz/">
```

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this error in NavitaireProvider while calling BookingCommit service (WCF Service Reference)

so, when we get cached proxy object then it will also retrived old SigninToken which still may not be persisted
so that not able to authenticate

so as a solution i called **Logon** Service when i get this exception to retrieve new Token

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for such unexpected behavior could be the presence of an additional DLL file with a different name in the bin folder, alongside your main **MyService.dll**. For example, a file named **MyService**_copy.dll. Removing this duplicate DLL from the bin folder may resolve the issue and result in smoother operation of the service.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by setting UseCookies in web.config.

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

and setting enableVersionHeader

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="1200" shutdownTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="103424" />
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was resolved when I commented the following line in Web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

Answer (score -4):

My solution was rather simple: backup everything from the application, uninstall it, delete everything from the remaining folders (but not the folders so I won't have to grant the same permissions again) then copy back the files from the backup.