# Web service return only XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, axis

I am consuming a web services using Service Reference.

I converted the result return using ToString().

```
using (ConnectClient client = new ConnectClient("ESConnect"))
                {
                    result = client.actiService("ssss", "sss", "sss").ToString();
```

The I use xml.linq to read the xml.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result)))
```

I get the following error:

```
The content type text/plain of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.
```

EDITED:

The web service is created using Apache Axis SOAP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243929/wcf-service-client-the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-me

Comment: Please add the actiService method code

Comment: add a break point on "result" line and check what is coming in it from service. Seems it is not returning well formed xml.

Comment: It does return an valid xml, but maybe the header does not tell it is a xml?

Comment: I cannot give actiService code, because it is a third party solution.

Comment: Do you need to do: result = client.actiService("ssss", "sss", "sss").InnerXML.ToString();

Comment: What type does the method return?

Comment: after result = client.actiService("ssss", "sss", "sss").InnerXML.ToString(); it will go to exception.

Comment: I meant what datatype does the method return?

Comment: It should get a xml string, what I get is html page or a empty plain/text.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just parsing an XML string you could try [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx)

Comment: Yes I am using it XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

Comment: The XDocument and XmlDocument classes are not the same. What's the error you see with XDocument.Load?