# Receiving default website when invoking web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I have created a web service and can invoke the methods using the WCF Test Client when the service is running on my local server (ASP.NET Development Server).

However, when I publish the web service to QA server and invoke one of the methods, again with the Test Client, I get the following error message:

```
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
```

Upon inspection of the request using Fiddler I see that what I am getting back is the default page as if I had visited the mywebservice.svc:

```
You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
```

I do not understand why the default page would be returned instead of invoking the method. Do I need to do anything on the server to allow the method to be invoked? Do I need to set up any MIME types?

Comment: Check these two posts and see if it helps -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263150/the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243929/wcf-service-client-the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-me